# 8266 get uint8_t PROGMEM array from uploaded file

Tags: esp8266, web-server, convert

I'm new programming arduino. I have connected an Adafruit thermal printer to an ESP8266 board.

I've the example code for use the board like a webserver that allow upload files. What i want is to upload a BMP file, convert it to an array of "uint8_t PROGMEM", and send the array to the printer in order the image would be printed.

Do you know any code i could use to convert the BMP file to "unint8_t PROGMEM"???. When i get the uploaded file it is an array of "unsigned char".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you want the array to be in PROGMEM?

Comment: It's required to send it to the printer

Comment: All the examples I saw were in that way. Tell me other ways, please

Comment: add one of the examples to the question

Comment: Sorry Juraj, I think you don't know what we are talking about at all or you don't want to know. Bye

Comment: one day you will understand, that bytes are bytes and you can copy them from any input to any output. no matter if from PROGMEM or from SPIFFS to a terminal, printer or buzzer. so show me the function that takes a PROGMEM data and I tell you how to modify it for bytes from SPIFFS files. or I will take a look at the library you use and search for a function which takes a stream